# WSO2 Identity Server SCIM API to retrieve a list of Groups

Tags: wso2, ldap, wso2-identity-server

I've created a userstore mapping all connections details of an already existing ldap with more than 200 groups. I'm using WSO2 IS 6.1 .I can see users and groups of this ldap through WSO2 IS admin console.

Using Groups SCIM API, I cannot see groups that were created in the ldap before connecting to WSO2. If I filter by group name, I only find groups created in WSO2 IS (that they were "synced" to the ldap), but if I try groups already existing in the ldap, SCIM API cannot found them.

Is this a limitation of the SCIM API or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in IS-6.1.0 and fixed in the latest version to be released (IS-7.0.0)

Refer to the git issue: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/19145

Before the fix, the group's unique id and other SCIM related meta attributes were resolved from IDN_SCIM_GROUP table in the identity DB of the WSO2 IS.
Since the SCIM related metadata of existing groups of a connecting LDAP is not available in IDN_SCIM_GROUP is the problem, and before the fix there was not an option to retrieve these meta details through attribute mappings of the user store.